# Extract records based on a condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

I want to extract only the rows where `OrderofEvents` 1 is followed by 2. For example, the data is ordered by `EventTime` and whenever the `EventName` changes the `OrderofEvents` changes. whenever the `OrderofEvents` changes I want to extract that row and the previous row. Below is how the input data looks like-

```
EventName             EventTime       OrderofEvents
AddedtoCart       2020-02-22 11:40         1 
AddedtoCart       2020-02-23 12:40         1   
AddedtoCart       2020-02-24 01:40         1   
Billed            2020-02-24 01:42         2   
AddedtoCart       2020-03-01 02:40         1   
AddedtoCart       2020-03-02 03:40         1   
AddedtoCart       2020-03-02 04:40         1   
AddedtoCart       2020-03-03 05:40         1
```

The output should look like -

```
EventName             EventTime       OrderofEvents 
AddedtoCart       2020-02-24 01:40         1   
Billed            2020-02-24 01:42         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(OrderofEvents) over (order by eventtime) as next_ooe,
             lag(OrderofEvents) over (order by eventtime) as prev_ooe
      from t
     ) t
where (OrderofEvents = 1 and next_ooe = 2) or
      (OrderofEvents = 2 and prev_ooe = 1) ;
```

This returns both events.

Comment: ... all the `EventTime`s are different, so the partition just causes extra work (and then returns no results)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . LOL.  That shouldn't have even worked.  It should be `order by`.  `lag()` and `lead()` should require an `order by`.

Comment: Still doesn't work, because no `OrderOfEvents` entry is `0`...

Comment: (and you don't need the `LAG` or the specific value checks, since you can compare against the current entry for the change)

Answer (score 2):

Use `lead` function

```
     Select * from table
       where 
       OrderofEvents<> lead(OrderofEvents) over ()
```

Or if above is not supported try this

```
      WITH CTE AS 
    (Select *,lead(OrderofEvents) over (order by (SELECT NULL) 
       )as lg
       from table)
       Select * from CTE where
       OrderofEvents<> lg
```

Comment: just do `OrderofEvents <> lag(OrderofEvents)  over()`

Comment: Yeah exactly, makes the SQL much shorter thanks man!

Comment: just noticed one thing, you should rather use `lead` and not `lag`. if you use `lag` then it will give you `2, 1` while lead will give you `1, 2`. Also the default should be the first value

Comment: Order by can prevent it but your point is also right lead could prevent it straight forward. corrected in the answer

Comment: On at least PostgreSQL, the current version of this statement generates a syntax error "Window functions are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause" - what RDBMS does it run on?  That aside, without an `ORDER BY` clause the statement returns non-deterministic (effectively random) results.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja This doesn't return the correct AddedtoCart event (exact previous event to the Billed event)